# Counting permutations of a set that doesn't fix elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to know how to count the number of permutations of a finite set that doesn't fix elements, i.e., the cardinality of the set $H=\{f\in S_n: f(i)\not = i\   \mbox{for}\  1\leq i \leq n\}$, where $S_n$ is the set of permutations of a set of cardinallity $n$.

I've been trying different ways, like counting for small numbers and try to see a relation or looking for a way of counting them, but none of them leads me to the answer.

Comment: Look up **derangements**.

Comment: Inclusion Exclusion Principle i.e. derangements in this case as David suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect answer using the inclusion exclusion principle:

http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Number_of_permutations_with_no_fixed_points_%28derangements%29

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself, here's a hint:

If a permutation in $S_n$ fixes an element, then by ignoring that element, the permutation 'looks like' an element of $S_{n-1}$. There is a formal way to make this statement precise.

There are $n$ different elements that may be fixed, and a permutation may fix up to $n$ of them! Use cyclic permutations to relate them, but be careful of double-counting.